# How to add image button to a link using html in javascript

Tags: javascript

The image button is not working perfectly.. any suggestions ?

The current code on which i am working is:-

```
var generator = window.open (); 
 generator.document.write('<html><head><title>Pop uP</title>');
generator.document.write('<p style="color:#C52B27;">');
generator.document.write(message);
 generator.document.write('</p>');
generator.document.write('</head><body>');

 generator.document.write('<a href="javascript:self.close()"><img src="/img/save_orange.gif" border=0"><\/a>');
generator.document.write('</body></html>');
generator.document.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Bind a js snippet to onclick event of the image

```
<img src="/img/save_orange.gif" border="0" onclick="self.close()">
```

According to this [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.close), `self.close()` only works if the document is open by `window.open()` method. <strike>So, on this case you might want to use `windows.close()`</strike>

Comment: `javascript:` in the attribute is not required, some even say it should never be there.

Comment: @MMM That pseudo-protocol in attribute is usefull when using more than one scripting languages within the same page.

Comment: @Starx..i am getting a cross mark .used it this way    generator.document.write('<img src="/img/save_orange.gif" border=0" onclick="self.close()"></img>')

Comment: @Teemu: Since Netscape the default scripting language is JavaScript.

Comment: @rcky, `<img>` is a self closing tag, you dont need the additional `</img>`

Comment: Still having that quotemark error in your code? (`border=0"`) @MMM In IE you can use VBScript mixed with JavaScript.

Comment: @rcky There is one quote `"` missing after `border=`.

Comment: @Starx....i am not getting image ..istead of that a blurred cross mark and self.close is working fine

Comment: @Starx  the code os  generator.document.write('<img src="/img/save_orange.gif" border="0" onclick="window.close()">')

Comment: @rcky, update your question with the parsed html as it written on the page.

Comment: @rcky, can't you use document.write, instead of `generate.document.write()`?

Comment: @rcky, This works perfectly `document.write('<img src="/img/save_orange.gif" border="0" alt="test" onclick="window.close();" />');`

Comment: @Starx...the above code (without generator variable )results in permission denied error

Comment: @Starx..for complete code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603734/how-to-set-focus-on-the-last-element-for-which-the-window-pop-ups-on-error

Comment: @rcky, its a security feature not to let the browser close the window it didn't open. So the problem at last is now that, I am sorry, but I dont know anything else we could do in this situation.

Comment: @rcky, wow a path problem. Really, I never suspected that. LOL. I am glad, it solved your problem.