# <html: image directly calling struts action class

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts

I  want to call submitformFinal(this.form);  which is a client side validation.But the problem is that **html:image** property directly calls struts, so the server side validation takes place before calling the submitformFinal(this.form).
If submitformFinal fails , server side validations should not take place ,but in this case html:image directly calls the struts action classs.... any suggestions?

Right now my code is:-`<html:image

                    src='<%=contextPath + "/img/save_orange.gif"%>'
                    onclick="javascript:submitformFinal(this.form); "/>`

Comment: show the changeAction, checkMultiSelects, and submitFormFinal JavaScript functions.  It seems likely that something is submitting the form before you think it is.  Also, you are not "calling" a struts action from JavaScript.

Comment: @DwB...edited my problem....hope it will make it more clear

Comment: The img tag is not calling anything.  It is not submitting your form either.  Show the submitformFinal() source.  It seems likely that the problem lies therein.

Comment: @DwB.this is the link to my submitformfinal http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603734/how-to-set-focus-on-the-last-element-for-which-the-window-pop-ups-on-error

Comment: @DwB...if i use <img tag, it is not calling anything but when i am using html:image , it acts as submit button as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about returning the value from `submitformFinal()`:

```
<html:image src='<%=contextPath + "/img/save_orange.gif"%>'
            onclick="return submitformFinal(this.form);"/>
```

Now if `submitformFinal()` returns `false` it wont submit, if it returns `true` then it will be submitted.

Update :

After seeing your next problem, here is my thoughts.

1) You should not use `<html:image>` for submitting the form. `<html:submit>` is the correct submit button tag. I will recommend to change the `<html:image>` to `<html:submit>`. U can add the image to the button by `styleId`, `styleClass` attributes. No need to call onClick on the button. It will just submit your form when you click it.

2) Now add `onSubmit` on the `<html:form>` tag like this:

```
<html:form action="someAction.do" onSubmit="return submitformFinal();">
```

This will work like as desired I guess.

Comment: I am glad it worked :)   I also learnt about <html:image> from your post.

Comment: @tusar.....but i got a problem as well.......when the submitformFinal() returns false, after that if i click the save button , then the login page opens....any ideas ?

Comment: @tusar......<html:image> is my assignment requirement and on click there are three events to be called onclick="javascript:changeAction('save');checkMultiSelects();submitformFinal();" />

Comment: You could call only `submitformFinal();` with `onClick` of `<html:image>` and the first two lines of `submitformFinal()` function definition will be then, `changeAction('save'); checkMultiSelects();`