# Left Navigation Validation

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a master page in which leftnavigation.jsp and header.jsp are present.Now leftnavigation contains hyperlinks to few of the webpages(say general.jsp, contact.jsp).On clicking these hyperlinks , these webpages gets opened.like if i click general link, it gets opened, and if i click the link of contact.jsp , contact webpage gets opened.Now these webpages have validations on the save button at the end of the form .

Now i want to have these validation (every webpage has a validation function on save button)to work when a user clicks a link on the left navigation to change the webpage.
 The leftnavigation.jsp does not contain any form element. it just contains links or scripplets
any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Listen for a `click` event on your navigation links then run your validation function:

```
function listen(event, elem, func) {
  if (elem.addEventListener) {
    elem.addEventListener(event, func, false);
  } else if (elem.attachEvent) {
    elem.attachEvent('on' + event, func);
  }
}

var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

listen('click', links, validationFunction);
```

If you're passing in variables, then wrap your validate function in an anonymous function:

```
listen('click', links, function(param) { validationFunction(param); });
```

Comment: ......i am getting null error as i am passing the forms dynamically in validationFunction. The validation function is named by submitformFinal(frm) in the code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603734/how-to-set-focus-on-the-last-element-for-which-the-window-pop-ups-on-error posted by me before.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds simple enough. You could make the navigation bar links call the validation function for the forms when clicked. Something like this perhaps:

`<a href="anotherpage.jsp" onclick="validate(); return true;>Click me!</a>`

Just a warning though: it's impossible to guarantee validation in this manner, users could bypass the validation (the user could click a back button for example). If this is what you're trying to achieve, consider running a validate function `onpropertychanged` or `onkeyup`. And, as always, form validations should (almost) never be a hinderance; don't show `alert` messages or do anything REALLY distracting if a user doesn't type something right.

Notice how the code above would let the user change pages regardless of the form's validation status. You could make the `onclick` function return `false` if the form failed validation, but this can be bypassed, and it is a hinderance to users.

If this is really necessary, have the links work regardless, but show a small message, possibly in the form of a `div` quietly pop up at the top of the page warning the user that one of their form entries was incorrect.

Comment: ......how to pass the formname(general.jsp or contact.jsp) dynamically to the validate function when it is used in leftnavigation.jsp wjich only contains links ans this validation function is defined in common.js

Comment: Wait a minute... you're not using `frames`, are you? If not, the pseudo code above just shows that you need to add an `onclick` function to the links in your navigation bar. It also might help if you show some more code in your question.

Comment: .....thanks for the help ...got the formnames dynamically by passing documents.form[0] to the parameter of the validation function